# Kendo UI MVC - Display None in HtmlAttributes

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a Kendo ComboBox like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
     .Name("LHWR")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px; font-size:small; display:none" })
     .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem() {
               Text = "Leave unchanged", Value = "0"
            },
            new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Deactivate", Value = "1"
            },
            new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Activate", Value = "2"
            }
      })
      .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

The "display: none" doesn't work, it hides the "input" tag but not the "span" tag:

```
<span class="k-widget k-combobox k-header" style="width: 150px; font-size: small;">
 <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
   <input name="LHWR_input" class="k-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="524288" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="LHWR_listbox" aria-activedescendant="LHWR_option_selected" aria-busy="false" style="width: 100%; font-size: small;">
   <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-select"><span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="LHWR_listbox">select</span>
 </span>
</span>
<input id="LHWR" name="LHWR" style="width: 150px; font-size: small; display: none;" type="text" data-role="combobox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"></span>
```

And then the ComboBox is still visible.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact problem, and it is possible to use `display: none`, but you likely have something conflicting with the display, e.g. in-line styling overwriting it, etc. The quickest non-jQuery solution is to simply give it a class in the `.HtmlAttributes()` like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
     .Name("LHWR")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px; font-size:small;", @class = "hiddenInputBoxClass" })
     .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem() {
               Text = "Leave unchanged", Value = "0"
            },
            new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Deactivate", Value = "1"
            },
            new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Activate", Value = "2"
            }
      })
      .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

and then adding to your css stylesheet:

```
.hiddenInputBoxClass {
    display: none;
}
```

This works because the class added via `HtmlAttributes()` will be applied to the enclosing span field, which will then hide your element.

And for reference, contrary to the other answer, the proper way to do this (according to Telerik) in jQuery is as follows:

```
$("#LHWR").data("kendoComboBox").wrapper.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it using javascript and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LHWR").closest(".k-widget").hide();
});
```

Comment: I really cannot do it outside, i have to do it inside that htmlattributes.. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hide the kendoDatePicker using below code

```js
 $("#kendo-date-picker-id").data("kendoDatePicker").wrapper.hide();
```

Comment: This question is about a "kendoComboBox", not a "kendoDatePicker." And you basically just copied the last line of of my answer anyway.